# model.isValid always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.validation.js

When I call `isValid()` on my backbone model it always returns `undefined` even when the validation rules have been met or not. What could be going wrong here?

What could be the problem here and how can I fix it?

My Model:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({

    validation: {

            firstname: { required: true, msg: _('First Name is required').translate() }
        ,   lastname: { required: true, msg: _('Last Name is required').translate() }
    }
});
```

My view:

```
Backbone.View.extend({

        events: {
            'submit form[data-action="specify-pbt"]': 'specifyPBT'
        }

    ,   bindings: {
            '[name="firstname"]': 'firstname'
        ,   '[name="lastname"]': 'lastname'
        }

    ,   initialize: function(options) {
            this.model = options.model || new PBTSpecifyModel(); // The latter condition is always met

            BackboneCompositeView.add(this);
            BackboneFormView.add(this);
            Backbone.Validation.bind(this);
        }

    ,   specifyPBT: function (e)
        {
            var options = jQuery(e.target).serializeObject();

            console.log("model: ");
            console.log(this.model);  // Outputs the model: looks all correct
            console.log("isValid: ");
            console.log(this.model.isValid()); // Outputs undefined
            console.log("validationError: ");
            console.log(this.model.validationError); // Outputs null
        }

    ,   getContext: function()
        {
            return {

            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Use method  `isValid(true)`

Comment: I see you've asked other questions already without giving feedback here. If any of the answers have helped you, you could upvote and/or accept one. If no answer was enough, it's encouraged to write and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation before asking questions.

> [isValid](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isValid)  `model.isValid()`
>   Run validate to check the model state.

> [`validate`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) `model.validate(attributes, options)`
>    This method is left
>   **undefined** and you're encouraged to override it with any custom
>   validation logic

You're using a plugin, not validation methods of backbone itself. Follow the plugins instructions on how to check validation state.

Answer (score 0):

[Backbone.Validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation) has a documentation entry on its version of [`isValid`](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation#isvalid) which differ from the default Backbone one.

> Check to see if an attribute, an array of attributes or the entire
>   model is valid.
>
> **`isValid` returns `undefined` when no validation has occurred and the
>   model has validation** (except with Backbone v0.9.9 where validation is
>   called from the constructor), otherwise, true or false.
>
> If you don't pass an argument, the properties defined by the
>   attributes bind option will be validated. If no attributes option is
>   used there will be no validation.
>
> ```
> var isValid = model.isValid();
> ```
>
> If you pass true as an argument, this
>   will force a validation before the result is returned:
>
> ```
> var isValid = model.isValid(true);
> ```
>
> If you pass the name of an
>   attribute or an array of names, you can check whether or not the
>   attributes are valid:
>
> ```
> // Check if name is valid
> var isValid = model.isValid('name');
>
> // Check if name and age are valid
> var isValid = model.isValid(['name', 'age']);
> ```

The [default `isValid` of a Backbone Model](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/539c9afad9c0af986704b26ea55ab62336c64fa2/backbone.js#L776-L789) will always return a boolean.